# Jenkins Root User permission as root user

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I am running a script with `Started by user Root User` shown in the configuration. The script runs well with `crontab -e` and also run with no error when I run manually in terminal. Does `Jenkins` job need special configuration for permission? I don't get it why it is not working while `crontab -e` works.

Please let me know

Comment: Please clarify your question. If something is not working, please show us exactly what is not working and why do you think it is not working. Do you see an error message? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the command is running fine when run through command line (and cron), then it mean Jenkins is not running with the same user with which you're running it on command line (or cron). If it is possible (and feasible) for you to change, then try running Jenkins with the same user.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want jenkins to run all jobs as root.

see [link](https://medium.com/@farooqyousuf/how-to-run-jenkins-using-the-root-user-in-linux-centos-79d96749ca5a#.pyshuihf0) as to how to do that.

basically, change /etc/sysconfig/jenkins :

```
$JENKINS_USER="root"
```

and change  the ownership of the jenkins folder:

```
chown -R root:root /var/lib/jenins chown -R root:root /var/cache/jenkins chown -R root:root /var/log/jenkins
```